# Wrap each item in my dataset with double quotes not reading to csv

Tags: python, list

This is driving me nuts.

**Input:**

| id | name | last_name | datetime | lat | long |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stack | Overflow | 2024-01-01 | 40.21324 | 39.6969 |  |

**Desired output:**

| id | name | last_name | datetime | lat | long |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "1" | "Stack" | "Overflow" | "2024-01-01" | "40.21324" | "39.6969" |  |

Issue: I am able to wrap each item in double quotes in Jupyter Notebook but when I read to CSV I lose the double quotes.
I have a dataset with a bunch of different fields.
For example:

```
123, Peter, 40.83429, 2023-10-23
```

I want to wrap every field with a double quote:

```
 "123", "Peter", "40.83429", "2023-10-23"
```

My code:
What happens when I read back the csv in Jupyter Notebook:

Code to add double quotes:

```
all_cols = list(df) 
for i in all_cols:
    df[i] = '"' + df[i] + '"'
```

Code to read that into the csv:

```
df.to_csv('test1.csv')
```

However, when I open my CSV file it's STILL not wrapped in double quotes. What am I doing wrong? Thank you SO MUCH in advance this is driving me absolutely nuts.

Comment: So, no running example to experiment with?

Comment: I would like to understand WHY you want that.  That is not standard behavior for a CSV file.  Any program that can read a CSV will be able to handle that file without quote marks.  Quoting the numbers seems especially counterproductive.  However, you don't need the gigantic `pandas` package to do this.  It's a simple Python loop.

Comment: When I tried your code, I got `0,"""123""","""Peter""","""40.83429""","""2023-10-23"""` in the CSV. That's how literal quotes are represented in a CSV file.

Comment: @TimRoberts - Its a common thing to do. In fact, there's a flag for that. `df.to_csv('test1.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)`. Come to think of it, that's the answer.

Comment: (1) Show a sample of the created `test1.csv`. (2) How do you read it back in?

Comment: @TimRoberts Not sure the WHY really matters here. Writing and reading quotation characters to a CSV is supported by pandas.

Comment: In my view, the "why" matters, because too many people get on a wrong track and ask how to implement an ugly workaround, when in fact there is a RIGHT answer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to_csv` method has a flag for that. It uses the QUOTE flags from the `csv` module

```
df.to_csv('test1.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
import csv

out = open('test1.csv','w')
for row in csv.reader(open('test.csv')):
    print( ','.join(f'"{x}"' for x in row), file=out)
```